# Cannot set the Database to use Localhost

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-core-mvc

I build a new .NET Core Web App (MVC).

[image]

Then Fill up all the information.
[image]

Then I try to change the connectionstring to point to my localhost.
[image]

[image]

[image]

When I check in appsettings.json, the default connection is still like this. Its still pointing to somewhere else. I try to run the application, it can run. I can register a new user.
[image]

So I change the connectionstring. Now, I thought this will piint to my localhost DB, but it didnt. When I run the application, its still connected the the other database (unknown).
[image]

My question is, How can I point the DB to my localhost? Where is the DB it is currently pointing to?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

When you open your **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio**
befor click on **Connect** button you can see your **Server Name** ,
you should copy that and replacing that with localHost in your connection string .
and also if you set UserName and PassWord for your Sql use connection string should change like this

***Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;***

else you not set UserName and PassWord your  connection string should change like this

***Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;***